# Audio controlling

Tags: c++

I want to develop a small audio controlling software.  Only basic functionality like volume controlling, or / and bass controlling.

Comment: On Windows, mac, linux? And, volume of what?

Comment: From your comment on Chris's answer I see you're on Windows. And it sounds like you want to change the system volume, not play sounds and adjust the volume of them. In that case, you should tag this as Windows and explain it better.

Comment: Do you mean to control Windows audio or are you trying to develop an application that will play an audio file and let the user control audio output?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into OpenAL? It's simple enough to pick up quickly. It's also cross-platform, so you can code your stuff once and use it in Linux, Windows, Mac, etc.

Comment: Is that a software extension ? As im quite new with visual C++ I really dont know alot about these things

Answer (score 0):

Your question's a bit open-ended, but if you're after making software that you can load sounds with, and with which you can adjust volume and EQ, try out [Juce](http://www.rawmaterialsoftware.com/juce.php)